# Problem with chat privilege?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

In answering a question earlier today, I tried to move the extended discussion to chat, but the other chap told me he wasn't being let in despite a 34 rep. When I checked, his profile on the question said his rep was 34, but when I looked at the chatroom overview his rep was only 4. Anyone have any idea what was going on here?

Comment: Your rep is also 30 low, but mine is not. It's probably just hours-long [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) glitches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by caching.

The chat system doesn't get reputation changes instantaneously so there'll be a period where the main site says you can chat, but the chat system says you can't.

If the problem persists for longer than a day then raise an issue.